# Android Spinner not showing at first run

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a spinner that is loaded by data from an sqlite table in an Async task as shown below:

```
private class setSectorsAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {

    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... booleen) {

        ArrayList<String> seclist = null;

        Cursor  curSectors = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(Contract.SECTOR_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

        if (curSectors != null) {

            if (curSectors.moveToFirst()) {

                seclist = new ArrayList<>();

                seclist.add(getResources().getString(R.string.select_sector));

                for (int i = 0; i < curSectors.getCount(); i++) {

                    seclist.add(curSectors.getString(curSectors.getColumnIndex(DB.Schema.Sectors.COL_SECTORS_NAME)));
                    curSectors.moveToNext();
                }

            }

            curSectors.close();
        }

        return seclist;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> seclist) {

        if(seclist!=null) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(AppActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_report_new, seclist);
            if(spinnerSector!=null){
                spinnerSector.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

This is called onCreate but behaves very erratically. When the application is installed the first time and the user navigates to the page, the spinner is blank with nothing to display. When one presses back and then navigates back to the page then the spinner will display as expected. Subsequent navigations back after this initial visit will always have the data.

What could be causing this?

Update: As requested the gist is as shown https://gist.github.com/Jaymo/a8eebbc4454412119e33e35b858a42b3

Comment: where you are adding data to database ?

Comment: Its added on first login of the app and I can gurantee its loaded in since other pages before this one have the data and the call to data is only done once so there is no  likely hood of their being no data

Comment: in that case show your whole class.

Comment: Could it be sync problems. Start the AsyncTask from the onCreate method but do not update the UI from the task. Listen on the Activity (implement an interface) and do it then. This is the way worked better to solve sync problems for me.

Comment: What is spinnerSector, Make sure you paste the whole class code

Comment: @SRBbans the whole class is huge I would have to gist it

Comment: @IsmailIqbal the initialised spinner

Comment: @James Wahome better gist it

Comment: @WalterPalladino instead of having the UI update on post execute? However what would be the reason for it showing only on second and subsequent runs?

Comment: @JamesWahome did you debug it, is it executing on first run.. ? try to debug it.

Comment: @SRBbans  I have updated to include the gist and yes I have debugged and it run the first time